# ExtJS Multi-ids stateful components

Tags: extjs

My problem is the following.

I have a component that I want to be stateful, and the state based on some ids (per user and per task basically) and this state is saved in my database.

Following some tutorials I managed to do a stateprovider that requests information through ajax requests.

Though I still have a problem since the restore event is only triggered when reloading the page, but not on task change.

Would there be anyways to trigger state change when tasks are opened.

Because the problem I have right now is if I force the restore, it happens but the task will somehow still be opened with the previous state (I guess because of the fact that the provider is asynchronous?)

Comment: Hi, could you provide a code example? You know that you can set the stateEvents on your component?

Comment: Hello @taubi19,
I did some more experiments, and I found out some things.
Especially the fact that RestoreState is normally only called at page refresh, which is not what I wanted, since I want to change the state when I open a task, which does not correspond to a page refresh.

I will put an answer with how I in the end did soon, I just didn't find time yet since I am still working on it.